# Can identification of a noun be done by prenominal modification?

Tags: attributive-nouns, appositives

I have seen many examples of identification of a noun by using prenominal modification, in which I had already expected it should be done by "apposition"; for example, in my opinion, the following example should be wrong:

- the \date command,

because the noun "\ *date*" does not semantically modify the noun *command* but is semantically identified by the noun *command*, and so should be treated as a restrictive appositive as follows:

- the command \date.

I wonder when and why we can employ prenominal modification instead of apposition for identifying a noun.

Comment: Appositive NPs are not pre-head but post-head modifiers, as in "the opera _Carmen_", "my wife _Lucy_", "our friend, _the mayor_".

Comment: With "generic head nouns" like ***command, instruction*** where a *single word* can identify one specific instance of the generic category, you can often see things in terms of a ***use/mention distinction***. So *The date command is documented here* is a ***use***, in that the word "date" is being used to modify the generic category noun "command". But *The command date is documented here* is a ***mention*** (the word "date" ***is*** a command, and it would often be in scare quotes or a different typeface in such contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I cannot understand your explanation about how the noun "\date" (not "date") modifies the generic noun "command". Please note that "\date" is the name of a specific command, like the title of a book. So, can we say, for example, "the Don Quixote book"? Can the title of a book semantically modify the noun "book"?!

Comment: Perhaps my "use / mention" distinction isn't helping you here. The difference between the two word sequences is that 1) *the **/date** command* uses ***/date*** "adjectivally" (as a "noun adjunct") to modify the "head" noun ***command*** (same as *the **car** radio*). But in 2) *the command **/date*** the actual "word" ***/date*** is effectively the "head" noun (where ***command*** just tells us more about what *kind* of thing that head noun actually is). Leading to 1a) *Use **that command** to amend the system clock*, and 2a) *Use **/date** to amend the system clock.*

Comment: "the Don Quixote book" would more naturally refer to ***any*** book that is in some way concerned with Don Quixote, rather than being called that. For example, a book containing critical reviews of "the book *[which has the title]* Don Quixote".

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you said, we refer to a book with title Don Quixote as "the book Don Quixote", **not** "the Don Quixote book" which is a book concerned with Don Quixote. So, analogously, we **should** refer to a command with title \date as "the command \date", **not** "the \date command", because we are not referring to a command concerned with "\date" but to a command with title "\date" (Please note that "\date" is just a name of a command). Similarly, we **should** say "the number 123", not "the 123 number". Am I right?

Comment: No - you're not exactly right, there. There's no element of "should" regarding the alternatives "the command \date" and "the \date command" (both are absolutely fine, and it's just a stylistic choice / matter of emphasis which you use). Note that **command + \date** isn't *quite* the same as **book + Don Quixote**, because it's quite natural to refer to *a book [which is] **called** "Don Quixote"*, but you wouldn't refer to *a command which is called "\date"*. In the former case, "Don Quixote" is the ***name*** of a book. But "\date" isn't a command *name* (it really ***IS*** a command).

Comment: ...on the other hand - Yes, you're quite right that we only say "the number 123", never "the 123 number". More accurately, that second one would require a *really* unusual context that I won't bother trying to expand on, because in practice such contexts would probably never arise. Just assume that for all practical purposes, "the 123 number" is idiomatically invalid.